# Does multi-tap fires evnets as a single tap?

Tags: android, multi-touch

Does multi-tap fires events as single-tap?
Events such:
click
pressed
released

and maybe more, because it uses another finger to create variations?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multitouch is detected the same way as simple touch: via `onTouch()`. The difference is in the supplied `MotionEvent`. You can check which point has been changed by `getPointerId(int)`.

For a complete example take a look at: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775